# squashing empty commit with a commit on a same branch

Tags: github

I have committed some code, below I have given my problem statement.
commits

```
   abcdef5 - empty
   qwerty5 - my code
```

Both of them are on my branch `abc`

How to merge both of them into 1 commit?
I just need `qwerty5` in my branch.

Answer (score 0):

If `abcdef5` is really empty (and it the most recent commit on your local branch `abc`), you could simply drop it:

```
git reset --hard @~
```

No squash required there.
Then you can push your branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to squash your empty commit:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

#### 1. Review the commits

```
pick abcdef5 a
pick qwerty5 b
```

#### 2. Squash commit a into b

```
s    abcdef5 a
pick qwerty5 b
```

#### 3. Edit the final commit message

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

message from commit a

# This is the 2nd commit message:

message from commit b
```

#### 4. Push your code

```
git push --force
```

Hope this helps. :)